# Remove/update line breaks from string in sql columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have done OCR on some books' titles which, for some reason, added line breaks too. Now I want to bulk remove/update them all permanently, not in select view. These are the queries I am running

```
SELECT Replace(BOOKTITLE, Char(13) + Char(10), ''), 
       Len(Replace(BOOKTITLE, Char(13) + Char(10), '')) 
FROM   BOOKTABLE; 

SELECT BOOKTITLE AS [(No column name)], 
       Len(BOOKTITLE) 
FROM   BOOKTABLE;
```

which yield following results

[image]

How can I get it done?

Comment: So. . . [UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) your table.

Comment: Isn't that obvious? What I want to know is, how. So that the line breaks are removed and records are retained.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, please add some more information and add desired output

Comment: @jimmy8ball I want to remove the line breaks from column BOOKTITLE, and because these are just line breaks that I want removed, there won't be visual results. So, just assume that the value is 'Applee' and the last 'e' is the line break, I want to make it 'Apple'

Comment: @Larnu, thank you for dumbing it down for me. Read the full comment though.

Comment: @Larnu I haven't tried update because I don't simply want to replace the entire value with nothing. I just want to omit the line breaks while retaining the letters.

Comment: @Larnu, because the level of expertise I have, I know only that full value is replaced. I don't know to manipulate characters in the string by updating.

Comment: @Larnu, please don't mind. I merely stated a fact.

Comment: Yeah, flag mine and remove yours.

Comment: @fasihullahkhan do you mean you need everything after the hyphen?

Comment: @jimmy8ball, No, I want the last two invisible characters (linebreaks, spaces) removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If line breaks are always at the end of BOOKTITLE then you can do this update

```
UPDATE BOOKTABLE SET BOOKTITLE = LEFT(BOOKTITLE, LEN(BOOKTITLE) - 2)
```

Comment: Isn't it going to remove the characters before hyphen?

Comment: `LEFT` is confusing me.

Comment: Then read the documentation on it so it doesn't: [LEFT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: LEFT function gets left part of the string where second argument is the number of characters to leave

Comment: I am getting `Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.`

Comment: Sorry, problem was at my end. Your answer has addressed my issue. Thank you.